# Why can a database file become corrupted if it's copied while in use?

Tags: corruption

Many sources online claim that copying a database file while it's in use can corrupt that file. But I couldn't find any explanation for why this is an issue, and I'm confused about it. Copying a file is a read-only operation on that file, so why should any of the data stored in that file get affected in any way?

Answer (score 2):

*Any* file can become corrupted if copied while being in use by another process. "Being in use" means that the other process can modify the file. Since the speed of copying is finite, it might happen that, by the time you copy the last bytes of the file, that other process has already changed the first bytes, thus making the copy inconsistent.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to my question? You've described why the *copy* might be corrupted, not the original file.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you were asking about the original file (as comments indicated), and you didn't clarify, so

Comment: @IsaacKing: Agree with mustaccio, it's not clear from your post whether you are talking about the source or the copy, which, in my opinion, is only half of the issue.  The other half is, it's unclear whether you yourself haven't misunderstood the many claims you mentioned.  Citing those claims, coupled with adding links to them (preferably), might make the subject matter clearer.

Comment: Creating a new file is obviously not a read-only operation on that file, nor does it make any sense to talk about a file being "in use" before it exists, so I'm really confused as to how you could have gotten that impression from my original question. But regardless it seems we're on the same page now, which is what matters.

Answer (score 2):

> Copying a file is a read-only operation on that file ...

Yes it is, but it is not "atomic".
The file is not *locked* while it is being read (to be copied) and the running database will continue to write to the file while the copy is running.  The database writes to the datafile in "Blocks" and these blocks can be written to *any part* of the file, at any time.  The copy process might have read the first part of the file, creating its copy, but then the database overwrites bits that have *already been read*.  As a result, the copy is incomplete and inconsistent.

Now there are tools/mechanisms that handle this (e.g. SqlServer's VSS) by effectively asking the database to "Stop writing to the Data Files for a bit, please" (which sounds good, but effectively "stalls" the database entirely).

The Basic Rules of Thumb, of course, should be

> Always do Database "Stuff" with Database Tools.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to my question? You've described why the *copy* might be corrupted, not the original file.

Comment: I do not see how the original could be corrupted.  
Perhaps if you cited some of the "Many sources online" that assert this, we might be able to comment.